# Wordpress Sticky Post Count "Fix" Breaking Pagecount by 72 pages!

Tags: posts, functions, pages, code, sticky-post

I have a permanent sticky post on my front page and have implemented the code (pasted below) into my functions.php file to stop it adding an extra post to my post count on the front page (it's a grid so i can't have one post dangling off the bottom).

However.... when the code is implemented it's adding a whopping 72 extra pages to my page count. From 799 (which is what it should be) to 871. Any page past 799 obviously comes up at 404 because  it doesn't exist.

Can someone please help me figure out what's causing it? Cheers

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query )
{
    if ( $query->is_home && $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
        $sticky_posts   = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

        // if we have any sticky posts and we are at the first page
        if ( is_array($sticky_posts) && !$query->is_paged() )
        {
            $sticky_count = count($sticky_posts);

            if ( $sticky_count < $posts_per_page )
            {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page - $sticky_count);
            }
            else
            {
                $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have a post you always want to show on the homepage, and only there, on that first page of posts, wouldn't it be easier to just display it if you're on page 1 just above the loop instead? Then set the homepage loop to not show sticky posts ( because you're displaying them manually )? Otherwise I believe the cause of your problem is the very thing you're trying to do. IMO The solution is to not do it and find an alternative solution

Comment: Thanks, i get what you are saying but the reason i'm using the above method is for two reasons. A, i edit the post a lot and it would be much easier to do it from the WP backend. B, as my site is a grid 4x3.. if i added the post manually i would still have the same problem of: one static post plus WP printing 12 more, therefor having 13 posts on the front.

Comment: Is a design based solution not tenable in any way shape or form? Is there a reason you asked how to fix your solution rather than how to solve your problem?

Comment: No no reason, i'm open to anything really. I just need the grid to stay tidy on every page with a sticky on the front page only.